# Javascript. How I call a prototype method given that methods name as a string plus args?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an object with a set of prototype methods. How do I invoke that method given is name and arg list?

So I have and object:

```
scarpa.MyThing = function() {
}
```

`MyThing` has a prototype method:

```
scarpa.MyThing.prototype.beAwesome = function(a, b, c) {
    // do awesome stuff here with a, b, and c
}
```

Now, I want to call `beAwesome` from another prototype method:

```
scarpa.MyThing.prototype.genericCaller = function(methodName, d, e, f) {

    // this does not work for me
    this.call(methodName, d, e, f)

}
```

Here is the call to `genericCaller`:

```
this.genericCaller('beAwesome', alpha, zeta, bravo);
```

I am stuck on the proper syntax for the call within `genericCaller`.

Can someone please enlighten me? Thanks.

Comment: @ahitt6345 that wont know the proper prototypical bindings, and eval is bad.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the `// this does not work for me` bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use bracket notation and apply

```
scarpa.MyThing.prototype.genericCaller = function(methodName) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);  //converts arguments to an array
    args.shift(); //remove the method name
    this[methodName].apply(this, args);  //call your method with the current scope and pass the arguments
};
```

Nice thing with using arguments is you do not have to worry about the d, e, f all the time. You can pass in 20 things and it will still work.

Comment: I like this one the most because it's variadic. edit- just saw your edit saying the same thing.

Comment: @Antiga After I posted and saw 2 other answers using .call, I thought I should point out why this is a little better. :) Than I saw your comment after the edit. lol

Comment: Yep. Nifty. JS is like the gumby language. Coolness. Cheers.

Comment: There is actually a bug in your code snippet. I use args.shift() instead of args.pop(). Shift clobbers the method name. Pop clobbers the last arg in the arg list. Minor nit.

Comment: Must have been the lack of coffee... :)

Comment: No worries. This is actually a huge help in my ability to fully grok JS which I am warming to. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There were quite a few errors in that code. Try this.

'call' is a function which is available to Functions. You were trying to invoke it on an object(this). That wont work.

All you have to do is do `this[methodName].call()`. Call takes context as the first argument, so pass `this`. And then the remaining arguments.

```js
var scarpa = {};
scarpa.MyThing = function() {
}

scarpa.MyThing.prototype.beAwesome = function(a, b, c) {
    // do awesome stuff here with a, b, and c
    console.log(arguments);
}

scarpa.MyThing.prototype.genericCaller = function(methodName, d, e, f) {


    //this[methodName].call(this,d,e,f)
    this[methodName](d, e, f)

}

var m = new scarpa.MyThing();
m.genericCaller('beAwesome', "", "", "");
```

Comment: There's actually no reason to use `.call(this,`

Comment: Oops. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it like this?

```
scarpa.MyThing.prototype.genericCaller = function(methodName, d, e, f) {
    this[methodName](d, e, f);
}
```

This works because `scarpa.MyThing` is also an object, which elements you may get by `dot` or `[]`

Comment: There's actually no reason to use `.call(this,`